# showAsAction="never" not working on API 8

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have the following menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        android:titleCondensed="@string/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_undo"
        android:title="@string/signOut"
        android:titleCondensed="@string/signOut"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

The first menu shows fine, but the second one doesn't appear at all (does not appear that three dots for other menus).

I'm using AppCompat.

What is wrong?

On API >= 11 works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That item should be accessible via hardware menu key.

Comment: Forgot about that... I'm using an emulator. Thanks!